# Rmarkdown overlapping output

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt, htmlwidgets

I reported an issue https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/967 and am wondering is there a workaround (how to make this work) for this?

[image]

Reproducible example below (vary n and nGroup to see the effect - no overlap when n = 100 and nGroup=10):

````
---
title: "Test links to sections in DT"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE)

## DT Test

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(DT)

n <- 1000
nGroup <- 100

testDF <- data.frame(text=paste0("Section", 1:n),
                     number=1:n,
                     group=rep(1:(n/nGroup), n/nGroup))

datatable(head(testDF), caption="Whole table", rownames=FALSE, escape=FALSE, options=list(paging=FALSE, info=FALSE))

getDT<-function(x) {
  a <- list()
  a[[1]] <- htmltools::tags$h3("test1")
  a[[2]] <- datatable(x[, c("text", "number")], caption=htmltools::tags$caption(style="caption-side: top; text-align: left;", "Group: ", htmltools::strong(x$group)), rownames=FALSE, escape=FALSE, filter=c("none"), options=list(paging=FALSE, info=FALSE))
  a[[3]] <- htmltools::tags$h4("test1")

  return(a)
}

res <- lapply(split(testDF, testDF$group), getDT)

htmltools::tagList(res)
```
````

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the HTML your example produces, I see a bunch of `div` tags that look like this:

```
<div class="datatables html-widget html-widget-static-bound"
     id="htmlwidget-3efe8ca4aa087193f03e"
     style="width:960px;height:500px;">
```

Note the inline style that sets the height to 500 pixels.  However, the content inside the `div` is much taller than 500 pixels, so it's overflowing past the boundary of the `div`.

I'm not sure where the `500px` is coming from, but as a workaround you can override it with a different style.  E.g., add this at the top of your RMarkdown (after the header):

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.datatables { height: auto !important;}
</style>
```

---

Or, if you prefer to keep your RMarkdown uncluttered with CSS, put

```
div.datatables {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

in a separate CSS file, and link to it in the RMarkdown header, like this:

```
---
title: "Test links to sections in DT"
output:
  html_document:
    css: overlap_workaround.css
---
```

Comment: Thanks! Should be reported as an issue in my option, but this fixed it for me