# RMarkdown DT table hiding html document

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown, dt

I'm trying to generate a report from a Shiny application using R-Markdown.
I have a series of DT tables created in a for-loop to be rendered in my RMD HTML output file:
RMD setup:

````
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(knitr)
    library(DT)
    library(plotly)
    library(htmltools)
    
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
    ```

When I create the data table by itself, there is no problem:

    ```{r table1, echo=FALSE}
    DT::datatable(
      params$table1_data,
      rownames= FALSE,
      class = 'cell-border stripe',
      options = list(searching = FALSE, paging = FALSE, info = FALSE)
    )
    ```
    Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.
````

The HTML output file came out just right

[image: image here]

However, when I create multiple data tables in a for loop:

````
    ::: {style="margin-bottom:30px;"} 

       
    ```{r dataframes, echo = FALSE}
        # Building list of outputs
        dt_list <- htmltools::tagList()
        
        for(i in 1:params$n_files){
          # Extracting data
          df_input_data = params$langmuir_freundlich[[i]][[1]]
        
          # Creating tables
          dt_list[[i]] <- DT::datatable(
            df_input_data[,1:3],
            caption = params$table1_data[i, 2],
            rownames = FALSE,
            class = 'cell-border stripe',
            options = list(pageLength =15, searching = FALSE, paging = TRUE, info = TRUE)
          )
        }
        
        dt_list
     ```
     :::
    
     ### Next section
     Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.
        
        
        $$
        I = \frac{kC^{b}}{1+kC^{b}}
        $$
````

The tables look great, BUT for some reason, the last table (even if it´s just one table) is overlapping my NEXT SECTION, I'm actually only able to see the latex equation included.

[image: image here]

I have tried many versions of the for loop, but I believe the problem is somewhere else. I even tried adding a div<> with a style to add some space between the tables and the next paragraph with no success. Can anyone please help me to find out where the problem is?

Comment: Can you validate your version of the `rmarkdown` package? I can see this issue closed (https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/967) with a `1.7` milestone so if you are able to use a version newer than 1.7, does that help? If not, the reporter of the issue noted a workaround at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361888/rmarkdown-overlapping-output/42411142#42411142

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** based on @jav comment and this thread [Rmarkdown overlapping output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361888/rmarkdown-overlapping-output/42411142#42411142)

My `rmarkdown` package was up to date, so the solution was to add the div styles after the header:

````
---
title:  "my_solution"
author: "my_name"
output: html_document
---

<style type="text/css">
    div.datatables { height: auto !important;}
</style>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
`
````

``

Then add the tables in my for-loop

````
#### 1.1. Data frames
```{r dataframes, echo = FALSE}
# Building a list of outputs
dt_list <- htmltools::tagList()

for(i in 1:params$n_files){
  # Extracting data
  df_input_data = params$langmuir_freundlich[[i]][[1]]

  # Creating tables
  dt_list[[i]] <- DT::datatable(
    df_input_data[,1:3],
    caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
      style = 'caption-side: top; text-align: center;',
      paste0('Table ', n_table,': ', params$table1_data[i, 2], ' data frame')
    ),
    rownames= FALSE,
    class = 'cell-border stripe',
    options = my_options, 
  )
  
  # increment table counter
  n_table <- n_table + 1
}

dt_list
```
````

Resulting in these beautiful tables that don´t overlap my html document
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kveI2.png)